# How to change default timezone of WTForms input to MST

Tags: python, html, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I have a form from WTForms that allows a yoga instructor to create a yoga class. Right now it works fine, however once a class has been created, the time zone of the class start_date_time and end_date_time defaults to GMT time zone. So when the class populates on my javascript calendar, it converts the current GMT timezone to MST and the start and end times are shown with a 7 hour difference.

Is there a way to have the instructors datetime inputs to the default timezone to MST (Mountain Standard Time) through the ClassAddForm WTForm or a way to convert to MST in the Classes(db.Model) class model? Here are my forms model and class model:

------------------forms.py---------------------------------

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, TextAreaField, SelectField, DateTimeField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Email, Length
from wtforms.ext.sqlalchemy.fields import QuerySelectField
from wtforms.fields.html5 import DateTimeLocalField

class ClassAddForm(FlaskForm):
    """Form for adding/editing messages."""

    instructor = QuerySelectField(query_factory=choice_query, allow_blank=True, get_label='first_name', blank_text='(Instructor)')
    location = StringField('Location', validators=[DataRequired()])
    start_date_time = DateTimeLocalField('Class Start', format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M', validators=[DataRequired()])
    end_date_time = DateTimeLocalField('Class End', format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M', validators=[DataRequired()])
```

------------------------models.py-------------------------

```
class Classes(db.Model):
    """Connection of a follower <-> followed_user."""

    __tablename__ = 'classes'

    id = db.Column( db.Integer, primary_key=True,)
    class_instructor = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('instructors.id', ondelete="cascade"),)
    location = db.Column(db.String,)
    start_date_time = db.Column(db.DateTime,)
    end_date_time = db.Column(db.DateTime,)
    class_users = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id', ondelete="cascade"),)
```